# geom_rect rectangle disappears when used together with coord_sf in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a map with `ggplot2` and would like to have a rectangle surrounding it. I have tried to create the rectangle using `geom_rect` function, but whenever I include `coord_sf` function in the code chunk, the rectangle disappears. Below are the maps I got with the following codes. Classes of zone_map and ecoregion_polygon objects are "sf" and both are read in using `st_read` function.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = zone_map, color = "black", fill = gray62_transparent) +
  geom_sf(data = ecoregion_polygon, color = "black", fill = burlywood1_transparent) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 20, xmax = 50, ymin = 33, ymax = 47), color = "black", fill = NA)
```

[image]

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = zone_map, color = "black", fill = gray62_transparent) +
  geom_sf(data = ecoregion_polygon, color = "black", fill = burlywood1_transparent) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 20, xmax = 50, ymin = 33, ymax = 47), color = "black", fill = NA) +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=38 +lon_0=35")
```

[image]

As you see in the second map, the `geom_rect` rectangle disappears upon addition of `coord_sf` line. **How can I solve this issue?** I have tried to create another polygon using `st_polygon` function, but I obtained the same results. I also tried setting both objects' crs as the azimuthal `"+proj=laea +lat_0=38 +lon_0=35"` projection, which I want to plot my map in, and I got the same results. Below are the `st_crs` outputs of zone_map and ecoregion_polygon objects.

```
> st_crs(zone_map); st_crs(ecoregion_polygon)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4326 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4326 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insofar you did not provide a reproducible example, it is difficult to test a solution. I would say you could try creating an **owin** object:

```
library(spatstat)
library(maptools)

crs <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
window <- as(spatstat::as.owin(c(-27,36,34,67)), "SpatialPolygons") 
raster::projection(window) <- crs
```

Then you represent such window as follows:

```
library(broom)
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = zone_map, color = "black", fill = gray62_transparent) +
  geom_sf(data = ecoregion_polygon, color = "black", fill = burlywood1_transparent) +
  geom_polygon(data = broom::tidy(window),
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill = "transparent", color = "black") +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=38 +lon_0=35")
```

Hope it helps